# unable to connect to webserver by some people from outside

Tags: dns

We have a web server. Some people are unable to connect(with domain name) from outside while others are able to connect without any issue.

Moreover instead of the domain name if we type the public IP address, then we are able to connect. so this seems to be DNS issue.

I am basically a server administrator. At server level DNS settings are configured properly. So the network team had given report that there's no problem with resp to our networks.

So should we escalate it to our hosting provider then? else is there anything else either server admin or network admin needs to check?

Comment: Who are the people that can't connect? Are they internal to your network? Are you able to verify the network settings between a machine that can can connect and one that cannot (maybe provide a screenshot)? You haven't given us much information to help you with.

Comment: no. they are not internal to our network. They are external vendors trying to access our web server. based on some analysis we were able to find out that people who were trying to connect via a particular service provider were unable to connect using domain name. But with public IP they were able to.

Comment: This sounds like a problem for that ISP to solve then.